# Grails search mechanism

Tags: search, grails, controller

I have the folowing gsp page:

```
 <g:form controller="??" action="??">
    <h1>Search</h1>
    <g:submitButton name="search" value="Search"/>

    <div id="resultsHere">

    </div>

    </g:form>
```

What i want to do is, everytime "Search is clicked", the database is searched for that record, lets imagine im looking for book titles. So everytime i write a title, the database finds the books and print every data related to the books. How can i do that=?

My idea is having something similar to this in the div:

```
<ul>
<g:each in="${bookList}">
  <li>Name: ${it.name}, Locale: ${it.isbn}</li>
</g:each>
</ul>
```

So the point is, when the search button is clicked, the controller that handle that action should redirect the page to the same page, and pass the filtered list of books so it can be printed in the `<g:each in="${bookList}">` tag.

I would like opinions about this being the best solution in this case. I could also render the results in the page directly, but i would like to do some css for the lookings so i think that wont be a good idea using render. Any help would be apreciated, and if possible, some lights with the code (specially the filtering part).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have one action in your controller, and render out the list.

ie: as pseudo-code (and not complete)

```
BookController {
  def search = {SearchComamnd search ->

    def books = []
    if(search) {
      books = Book.createCritera().list {
        and { 
          title(search.title)
          author(search.title)
        }
      }
    }

    render [ books:books ]
  }

  class SearchCommand {
    def author
    def title
  }
}
```

and then when in your view

```
<g:form controller="??" action="??">
    <h1>Search</h1>
    <g:submitButton name="search" value="Search"/>

</g:form>
<g:each in="${books}">
  <li class="book">Name: ${it.name}, Locale: ${it.isbn}</li>
</g:each>
```

you can now use css `li.book` to decorate the entry.

Comment: @Gonzo I removed the resultsHere div because it's pointless and IMO it's preferable to have the results outside the form (as you suggest)

Comment: You'll need to add fields to form so that the user can enter the search parameters

Comment: @Don absolutely right ... but this isn't meant to be complete (or working on its own)